# Android Kotlin - Camera Intent low quality using fileProvider

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello I'm trying to view an image in an ImageView but the screen turns into black and does nothing. BTW I'm using a fragment and fileprovider.

var intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

```
                    val storageDir= getActivity()?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    photoFile=File.createTempFile(FILE_NAME,".jpg",storageDir)
                    val fileProvider= FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireContext(),"com.example.an0nym0us.fileprovider",photoFile)

                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileProvider)

                    startActivityForResult(intent, 3)
```

var bitmap:Bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.absolutePath)

Comment: "I'm trying to view an image in an ImageView" -- the code shown in your question is not doing that. If your `decodeFile()` line is the line right after your `startActivityForResult()` line, please understand that `startActivityForResult()` is not a blocking call. The camera app will not have even started by the time `startActivityForResult()` returns.

Comment: Sorry It's insinde the onActivity Function. I followed the guides using an activity but I wan to use a fragment and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

startActivityForResult is deprecated

you can get the camera image like this

```
getCameraImage.launch(uri)
```

where

```
private val getCameraImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { success ->
      if (success) {
      ...
      } else {
      ...
      }
```

Comment: But when I don't use fileprovider startActivityForResult works fine